# TextViews position collapsing after constraintset applies

Tags: android, layout, android-constraintlayout

I have loop which is positioning TextViews stored in ArrayList. List starts with one fundamental TextView, which already has its position, and foreach loop sets all others below previous one.

```
for(int i = 1; i<textViewsArray.size(); i++){
   TextView newone = textViewsArray.get(i);
   newone.setLayoutParams(decoy.getLayoutParams());
   constraintLayout.addView(newone);
   ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
   constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout);
   constraintSet.connect(newone.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, textViewsArray.get(i-1).getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
   constraintSet.connect(newone.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.guideline1, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
   constraintSet.connect(newone.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, R.id.guideline2, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
   constraintSet.constrainDefaultHeight(newone.getId(), ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
   constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
}
```

It works when array is executed once, so when it's positioning only 1 additional TextView under fundamental one. But when it's doing more iterations, all TextViews are stick to top of parent view which is Constraint Layout.

Comment: What is `foreach`?

Comment: Oh yes that was just a misspell

Comment: Have you verified that each `TextView` has a unique id? How are you setting those ids?

Comment: Please add your xml code too

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the `LayoutParams` from `decoy` and applying them to the other views such that all of your views share the same set, so a change in one causes a change in all.

To correct this, make a copy of the `LayoutParams` and apply the copy as follows:

```
newone.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(decoy.getLayoutParams()));
```

This way, each of your views gets it own set of `LayoutParams`.